# Drupal Computed Field with Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, simple-html-dom, drupal-computed-field

I have some `Computed Fields` and in these fields, I get some HTML codes with `simple_html_dom.php` class from some sites. Codes works perfectly on pages, but when I try to get these fields to use in a `View`, Drupal gives the following error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Rhc.jpg

Anybody can help?

Comment: Also I tried to use `Store data in database` feature of Drupal Computed Field, but nothing has changed so far.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not the best solution, after installing `Views PHP` module of Drupal, problem is slightly solved. I still get the error message on every time I try to change something, also I am having difficulties on making a change on the view, like saving and adding the same thing 5 times and got successfull, still it is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This message usually appears when you try to save the form before the ajax process has finished.

Try checking the 'network' tab on developer tools installed within Google Chrome or by using a tool similar to firebug. This will show you the request being made via ajax and should give you more information to debug.